# how to check for collisions in spritekit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

this has probably already been answered but I can't find any examples. Is there an EFFECTIVE way to detect collisions in sprite kit between nodes. I already tried to detect between nodes with this code.

```
if ([leftArrow intersectsNode:gravitySquare])
{
    //blah blah blah
}
else if ([rightArrow intersectsNode:gravitySquare])
{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

and this works but my character "gravitySquare" can sometimes pass through the edges of right arrow and left arrow with having no results (I assume this is because of the speed the nodes are going at). Is there a way to implement physics bodies to detect collisions without them having any actual effect on each other I mean to still pass through each other.

edit:

I added these as fields in the implementation file

```
static const int gravitySqrCategory = 1;
static const int arrowsCategory = 2;
```

I added this to the gravity square node

```
gravitySquare.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = gravitySqrCategory;
gravitySquare.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = arrowsCategory;
gravitySquare.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  arrowsCategory;
```

I added these to the two arrow nodes

```
leftArrow.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arrowsCategory;
leftArrow.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = gravitySqrCategory;
leftArrow.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  gravitySqrCategory;

rightArrow.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arrowsCategory;
rightArrow.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = gravitySqrCategory;
rightArrow.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  gravitySqrCategory;
```

and this is the did begin contact method

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
     SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

     firstBody = contact.bodyA;
     secondBody = contact.bodyB;

     if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == arrowsCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == arrowsCategory)
    {

        NSLog(@"hit"); 

    }
}
```

I also added this to the .h file

```
 <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```

extra information:

I have arrows coming from the left and right which I move with skactions so I originally didn't need to have physics bodies for them I just had a physics body on the gravity square so it could fly up and down. but now that i add the physics body to the arrows it makes the square fly around in tangents without even touching the spikes and i rarely get that "hit" nslog when in contact.

Comment: i am using phyicsbody with gravity square. could you be able to show me or redirect me to somewhere where i can learn how to detect for collision with physics with out the actual nodes being affected by the physics.

Comment: The SpriteKit programming guide covered it pretty well.  Other than that googling 'sprite kit collision detection' will get plenty of hits.

Comment: i got it going but it just makes my gravity square character fly around every where agghhh

Comment: Have you implemented the didBeginContact method? Please update your question with the same.